# How to prevent Word 2010 from stretching lines to keep words from breaking?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have this citation:

> Rudder, Sara Wallace. "Unmasking the Medical Millionaire Myth." Your Healthcare Financial and 
>   Money News Resource | Physician's Money Digest. Physician's Money Digest, 16 Sept. 2008. Web. 
>   06 Nov. 2011. http://www.physiciansmoneydigest.com/issues/2007/126/5281.

but Word streches the next to last line because it wants to keep the URL on one line.

I don't think this looks good (I'm using MLA style), so how do I stop it? (Or is it fine?)

Comment: Add a space after the domain portion of the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the paragraph justification from 'Justified' to 'Left'.

[image]

Usually it can be done just by selecting the left justification button as shown by the first green arrow. However, you may need to go to the paragraph properties (or the properties for the style) and change it on the Paragraph Properties screen shown below.

[image: Justification selection]

Answer (score 1):

MLA does not require a URL any more, but if you do choose to add one they suggest,

> that the URL appear in angle brackets after the date of access. Break
>   URLs only after slashes.

If your entire document is justified, try to keep the justification, as all else, consistent.

A tip: When you break the URL, sometimes Word chooses to add a hyperlink to the first half of the locator. Just hold your mouse over the link and right click. Choose "Remove Hyperlink".